# Quotients of schemes by connected groups

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups, group-actions

Let $X$ be a variety over $k$ where the characteristic of $k$ is zero. Let $G$ be a connected reductive group scheme acting freely and properly on $X$.

By the Keel-Mori theorem, the quotient $X/G$ is represented by an algebraic space. I would like to know if this can always be represented by a scheme, or else to construct a counterexample.

Let me remark that the standard counterexample to this question involves a finite group acting freely and properly on Hironaka’s threefold. I insist on the group $G$ to be connected

Comment: You can always replace a quotient $X/G$ for a finite group $G$ by a quotient $X'/G'$ where $G'$ is connected. Just embed $G$ in a connected group (say $GL_n$) and take $X' = X\times G'/G$ with the diagonal action.

Comment: @S.carmeli: Why is this $X'$ a scheme?

Comment: @LaurentMoret-Bailly its a product of $X$ (a variety) and the quotient $GL_n/G$ for a finite subgroup $G$, which certainly exist as a variety over a field of char $0$ right? Do I miss something here?

Comment: Well, it's $(X\times G')/G$, not $X\times (G'/G)$, right?

Comment: Oh, now I see the confusion. What i meant (which might be erroneous of course) is $X' = X\times (G'/G)$, with $G'$ acting diagonally. The quotient is then the same as $X/G$ but $X'$ is a variety again and $G'$ is connected, so you can realize every quotient by finite group as a quotient by connected group instead.

Comment: @S.carmeli How does $G'$ act on $X$?

Comment: Oh, I see, my mistake thanks!

Comment: If there are examples, then you can choose the reductive group to be semisimple (since torsors for multiplicative group schemes are Zariski locally trivial).  Similarly, you can eliminate any factors of $\textbf{SL}_n$ and $\textbf{Sp}_{2n}$ in your semisimple group.  These factors are "special" in the sense of Serre.

Comment: @JasonStarr Can you give me a hint for the case $G = \mathbf{G}_m$? Because $X/G$ is an algebraic space and although I know that $G$-torsors are Zariski locally trivial over a scheme, I don't know how this "works" over algebraic spaces.

Comment: For $\mathbb{G}_m$, the pushforward of the structure sheaf from the torsor is a coherent sheaf of algebras together with a $\mathbb{Z}$-grading, and the degree-$1$ "eigensheaf" is an invertible sheaf.

Comment: Yes. But why is $X/G$ a scheme?

Comment: Every trivialization of the invertible sheaf defines a section of the projection map, i.e., a closed immersion of $X/G$ into $X$.  An algebraic space is a scheme if it admits a finite morphism to a scheme.  Are you asking for a reference for Nisnevich's proof that etale locally trivial together with Nisnevich trivial implies Zariski locally trivial?  I think that is in Nisnevich's original paper on the Grothendieck-Serre conjecture.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\DeclareMathOperator\PGL{PGL}\DeclareMathOperator\GL{GL}$It seems that J. Kollár gave some examples in his paper "[Non-quasi-projective moduli spaces](https://doi.org/10.4007/annals.2006.164.1077)".

In pg. 1080, I think that there is an example of a proper free action of $\PGL(3)$ on a smooth quasi-projective variety $U$ such that the quotient $U/{\PGL(3)}$ is not a scheme. To be precise, $U$ is an open subscheme of the (projectivized) linear series of curves $\lvert\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^2}(d)\rvert$ and $\PGL(3)$ acts as automorphisms of $\mathbb{P}^2$. We have that $U$ is the open subset parametrizing curves $C$ such that:

(1) $C$ is integral, and the geometric genus of the normalization is $> \frac{1}{2}\binom{d-1}{2}$. (In the paper it says smooth irreducible instead of integral, but I think that this might be a typo?)

(2) The stabilizer $C$ under the action of $\PGL(3)$ is trivial.

Then it is show that the action on $U$ is free and proper (for properness of the action one may use [Stacks Lemma 32.16.2](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0CM4), which works for algebraic spaces with quasicompact separated diagonal, to assume that the generic fiber of the family over the DVR is smooth, as he does in his Claim 4). Kollár shows that for $d$ large, the quotient is a smooth algebraic space which is not a scheme.

I believe that the same would hold for the action of $GL(3)$ on the corresponding open subset $\tilde{U}$ of the affine (non-projectivized) space $H^0(\mathbb{P}^2, \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^2}(d))$. Then the corresponding étale $\GL(3)$-torsor on the quotient $\tilde{U}/{\GL(3)}$ should not be Zariski locally trivializable.

Answer (score 3):

**Edit.** As user @Johan observes, I need to find a reference for the following: every $G$-torsor for a "special" algebraic group $G$ (thus Nisnevich locally trivial) is Zariski locally trivial.  This is true for $G$-torsors over schemes, but the argument below needs this for algebraic spaces.

**Original post.** I am posting my comments [1](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/429489/quotients-of-schemes-by-connected-groups#comment1105096_429489) [2](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/429489/quotients-of-schemes-by-connected-groups#comment1105213_429489) [3](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/429489/quotients-of-schemes-by-connected-groups#comment1105233_429489) as an answer, mostly to address the issue raised by user @Johan [1](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/429489/quotients-of-schemes-by-connected-groups#comment1105206_429489) [2](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/429489/quotients-of-schemes-by-connected-groups#comment1105218_429489).  There is indeed some concern if you allow $X$ to be very singular.  However, in the case that $X$ is normal so that also $X/G$ is normal, Nisnevich's theorem (solution of the Grothendieck–Serre conjecture over spectra of DVRs) produces sections of the $G$-torsor $X\to X/G$ away from codimension $2$.  Since this $G$-torsor is an affine morphism, these sections should extend over codimension $2$ points by S2 extension (I guess I am not sure of a reference for that for algebraic spaces, but since extensions are unique if they exist, it should follow from the usual reference in EGA together with étale descent).

So if there are examples where a free quotient by a reductive group is an algebraic space that is not a scheme, then there are such examples where the group is a semisimple group with no factors that are "special" in the sense of Serre, i.e., no $A_n$-factors or $C_n$-factors.

Comment: Sorry, I do not agree with this argument or rather I cannot understand it. Sure, the algebraic space $Y = X/G$ is a scheme away from codimension $2$. But the thing about dvrs works only one dvr at a time. So given a codimension $2$ point $y$ of $Y$ I do not understand how you can find a rational section of $X \to Y$ which extends over all codimension $1$ points specializing to $y$ at the same time! Or is this not the strategy you had in mind? Very sorry to keep bothering you Jason!

Comment: I think this is what Nisnevich proved: if there is a section rationally, if there is a section etale locally, and if there is a section Nisnevich locally, then there is a section Zariski locally.  Maybe I am wrong!  I will check again Nisnevich's paper.

Comment: Maybe also you are saying that the cases of the Grothendieck-Serre conjecture that are proved for schemes are not all known for algebraic spaces (e.g., Grothendieck-Serre holds for groups that are "special" in the sense of Serre).  There is a paper of Reichstein and Tossici about variants of the definition of "special".  I have to think more about this.

Comment: Hey, wait a minute! Why is the definition of "invertible sheaf" in the Stacks Project given as "locally free of rank 1" if we do not know whether or not the (tensor) invertible objects in the category of coherent sheaves satisfy this definition?!?

Comment: Because "locally free" means: on the etale site of the algebraic space.

Comment: That makes sense.  Anyway, I do believe that Nisnevich's theorem applies, but I need to check it.

Comment: OK, if you have a reference, I can check it myself too. Thanks very much!

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to reply. I was wondering where in your proposed proof you are using the fact that $G$ is connected. The proof shouldn’t work for $G$ finite.

Comment: For disconnected groups, there is typically no trivializing Nisnevich cover.